# How and the best way to resolve this matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have the information that: distribution of probabilities is

$$ P_{X} =\{\frac{11}{24},\frac{7}{24},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8}\}$$
And the matrix has the form;
$$A= \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 p_{1}&p_{2}&p_{2}&p_{4}\\
 p_{2}&p_{1}&p_{2}&p_{5}\\
 p_{3}&p_{3}&p_{2}&p_{5}\\
 p_{3}&p_{3}&p_{2}&p_{5}\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

I have resolve:

$$A\cdot P_{X}=P_{X}$$

I can see that the sums of the columns is $1$
$$4p_{2}=1 \rightarrow p_{2}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Also we can see row 4 and row 5 are equal

so
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 p_{1}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&p_{4}\\
 \frac{1}{4}&p_{1}&\frac{1}{4}&p_{5}\\
 p_{3}&p_{3}&\frac{1}{4}&p_{5}\\
 p_{3}&p_{3}&\frac{1}{4}&p_{5}\\
\end{array}
\right]
 \cdot
 \left[
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{11}{24}\\
 \frac{7}{24}\\
 \frac{1}{8}\\
 \frac{1}{8}\\
\end{array}
\right]=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{11}{24}\\
 \frac{7}{24}\\
 \frac{1}{8}\\
 \frac{1}{8}\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
multiply except the last row(and add the last equation $=1$):
$$\frac{11}{24}p_{1}+\frac{1}{8}p_{4}=\frac{17}{48}\\
\frac{7}{24}p_{1}+\frac{1}{8}p_{5}=\frac{7}{48}\\
\frac{3}{4}p_{3}+\frac{1}{8}p_{5}=\frac{3}{32}\\
p_{1}+\frac{1}{4}+p_{3}+p_{4}+p_{5}=1$$

How can I continue and solve this?

Thank you very much

Comment: You’ve got a (likely undertermined) system of linear equations. Surely you know how to solve that. Presumably $A$ must be stochastic, so that adds some more equations to the system.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your comment. Yes, I can add one more equation $$p_{1}+\frac{1}{4}+p_{3}+p_{4}+p_{5}=1$$ . But now, how you can solve this?. Thank you so much

Comment: Solving a system of linear equations is fairly basic algebra. I’m a bit surprised that you’ve not encountered that before. For this system, nothing fancy is required. Three of the equations involve only two variables. Solve for one, back-substitute into the other equations, and repeat until done.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: write the system  as a matrix equation, say $Ax=b$, where $x=(p_1,\cdots,p_5)^t$ is a column vector of variables, $b$ is a constant column vector, consider the argumented matrix $B=[A \ b].$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&1&1&1&\frac{3}{4}\\
\frac{11}{24}&0&0&\frac{1}{8}&0&\frac{17}{48}\\
\frac{7}{24}&0&0&0&\frac{1}{8}&\frac{3}{32}\\
0&0&\frac{3}{4}&0&\frac{1}{8}&\frac{3}{4}
\end{bmatrix}
For  above matrix $B$, by  a successive elementary transformation of rows , simplifying $B$ to get an upper-triangular matrix, then solving the last equation to get solutions and iterating step by step